# $node object not populating with data

Tags: 7, rules, feeds, location

I'm using the Rules module to execute custom PHP script whenever a new node is saved after importing via Feeds module.

```
<?php

$lid = db_insert('location')->fields(array(
    'additional' => $node->field-address, //saves as '0'
    'city' => $node->field-locality, // saves '0'
    'province' => $prov, // //saves correctly
    'country' => 'xx', //saves 'xx' correctly
    'latitude' => $node->field-latitude-temp, //saves as 0.00000
    'longitude' => $node->field-longitude-temp, //same
    'source' => 1,
    'is_primary' => 0
))->execute();
```

This is the location table (from the Location module) and I'm importing data from a csv file.

All the other constant values are saved properly except for when it is coming from the $node object. Lat and Lon goes 0.00000 while all the other string values such as city and address also goes 0.

Been dealing with this for hours.

EDIT: I'm using Feeds module. But I need to import also location data. While a row is getting committed to db, the values are all 0!

node:field-latitude-temp shows the actual imported value correctly when viewing the node. But it is not getting absorbed in within the PHP Execute custom code page in Rules.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any reason you're not using the Feeds module? Also which hook are you suing? Are you sure its called after node save?

Comment: @Queenvictoria I have edited my post above.

Comment: From where you are getting the $node object? are you doing any node_load or the node object is supplied via any hook?

Comment: It is supplied by the 'Execute Custom PHP Code' page via the Rules module. I have edited to include an image.

Comment: @Queenvictoria Also, the Feeds module can't import data to Location, not sure why though, so what I did was to temporarily save it to another field and then let drupal copy that value directly to the database using the execute code.

Comment: Okay, I figured this out. I can use [node:field-latitude-temp] to pass the value to the database and it works. But still my question is outstanding to $node variable.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this can help you, but I don't think `$node->field-address` or `$node->field-longitude-temp` are valid syntax by `$node` object, you should use `$node->field_address['und'][0]['value']` or with `entity_metadata_wrapper` function, eg:

```
$nodeWrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$nodeWrapper->field_address->value()
```

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the issue, though I'd suggest trying `$nodeWrapper->field_address->raw()` to get a value more suitable for `db_insert`

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, you're right, `raw()` will be the right method for insert operations..

Comment: Thanks @xurshid29 for taking the time. Right now I just figured out I can use 'Location Feeds' to import location data using Feeds module. I have been looking for this. Though will keep your solution in mind.